# Javascript form validation "onKeyup vs on keydown"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Group,
I have a quick question? 
-Is there a way to trigger this onclick event when the last keypress is up.

for example: verify that newPwd==reTypePwd on the last keyup in reTypePwd text box. If my password is foo I would like for the event to trigger on "o" and not "f".

```
function allClear() {
 var newPasswd = document.getElementById('newPwd');
 var reTypePasswd = document.getElementById('reTypePwd');

 newPasswd.value = "";
 reTypePasswd.value = "";
 return true;
}
function validate()
 {
   var currPwd = document.getElementById("currPwd").value;
   var newPwd = document.getElementById("newPwd").value;
   var confirmNP = document.getElementById("reTypePwd").value;
   if(currPwd == "" || newPwd == "")
   {
      document.getElementById("btnChange").disabled = true;
      if(confirmNP!=newPwd){
      document.getElementById("confirm").value = "Doesn't Match";
    }
 }
     if(confirmNP!=newPwd)
     {
     document.getElementById("newPwd").style.cssText = "border-color:Red";
     document.getElementById("reTypePwd").style.cssText = "border-color: Red"; 
     } 
     else {
           document.getElementById("btnChange").disabled = false;
           document.getElementById("newPwd").style.cssText = "border-color:none";
           document.getElementById("reTypePwd").style.cssText = "border-color: none"; 

            }
          }
```

Thanks

Chad

Comment: How would the script know what the last letter of the password should be? Use the `onBlur()` event of the field. Plus you're testing that the user can remember their password, you're not supposed to provide hints that they 'should stop typing now,' they're meant to know. And, frankly, +1 to @lincolnk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't exclusively use onkeyup *or* onkeydown for detecting user input.  They don't catch the edge cases such as cut, paste, drag and drop or spell checker corrections.  You should use the HTML 5 event, *oninput* where available (Firefox 2+, Google Chrome, Safari 4+, Opera 10) and Internet Explorer's *onpropertychange* event.  For browsers that don't support either event, you can fall back to *onkeydown* with a 0ms timer for the check, which is a little better than *onkeyup*.

#### In newer browsers, you can check for the [*oninput*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) event, which should be the most reliable approach.

Comment: Sure and thanks....how do you accept questions i have a rep of 12 and I can't vote up on anything.

Comment: @Chad: On each answer to your questions there should be a check mark outline below the score/voting buttons.  Just click that to accept. You'll get 2 rep if you do and reach that 15 points milestone in no time.

Comment: The Link is broken

Comment: @AnkurAnand the blog has been down for years, unfortunately! Thanks for pointing this out so I could update the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing "when the last keypress is up" means when the two password fields contain values of the same length? If so, then have the keyup event listener first check the length of the values. For example, don't try to validate until the 2nd password length is equal or longer than the length of the 1st password. Of course, if the 2nd is longer than the first, it fails validation :)